# Ajax To (API Key) Button Click And Show Image Without Reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

I want to make a page where I can request images from multiple APIs and show them based on user's choice. User will choose whether they want to see a photo of cat, dog or fox by a click of button.

This is the code I have created :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>API</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <br>
     <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button type="submit" id="cat" onclick="ajaxSubmit();" name="cat" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Cat</button>
        <button type="submit" id="dog" onclick="ajaxSubmit();" name="dog" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Dog</button>
        <button type="submit" id="fox" onclick="ajaxSubmit();" name="fox" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Fox</button>

        <br>

        <img width="100" class="form-control"  style="border:#000; z-index:1;position: relative; border-width:2px; float:left" height="100px" src="<?php echo $upload_path.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];?>" id="thumbnail"/>
    </form>
</div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cat").ajaxSubmit({url: 'https://aws.random.cat/meow', type: 'post'})
    $("#dog").ajaxSubmit({url: 'https://aws.random.cat/meow', type: 'post'})
    $("#fox").ajaxSubmit({url: 'https://aws.random.cat/meow', type: 'post'})
</script>
```

This 3 API Endpoints to fetch the URL of an image :

```
Cat Pictures -> https://aws.random.cat/meow

Dog Pictures -> https://random.dog/woof.json

Fox Pictures -> https://randomfox.ca/floof/
```

I am trying to Last 3 hour but, No Response.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your code also doesn't make a lot of sense. Where is the `ajaxSubmit()` function defined? If you're expecting the `$("#cat").ajaxSubmit(..)` functions to be fired when the `click` event happens, that's not how Javascript or jQuery work. I would suggest you research event handlers.

Comment: Button Click and show to image API key Without reload in ajax @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: From you code you are trying to grab the result through AJAX. That will not work and result won't be shown on the page.
In the ajax calling you are not handling the correct response. Check your server side code as well.

Comment: @GauravKhatri It's an open API. So anyone can create a request and access data.

Comment: `Button Click and show to image API key Without reload in ajax` You don't need AJAX to show an image...? Again, this logic makes no sense. Please edit the question to give a full and clear description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Edited Queston. You can see.. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right question? The only edit made to this one was by @p01ymath

Comment: p01ymath is my best Friend..I Request to Edit.. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I have added an answer for you. The answer you accepted is just about the worst way to do what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <button type="button" id="cat" name="cat" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Cat</button>
            <button type="button" id="dog" name="dog" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Dog</button>
            <button type="button" id="fox" name="fox" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Fox</button>

            <br>

            <img width="100" class="form-control"  style="border:#000; z-index:1;position: relative; border-width:2px; float:left" height="100px" src="<?php echo $upload_path . $large_image_name . $_SESSION['user_file_ext']; ?>" id="thumbnail"/>
        </form>
    </div>



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#cat").click(function () {
            $.ajax({url: "https://aws.random.cat/meow", success: function (result) {
                    $("#thumbnail").attr('src',result.file);
                }});
        });
        $("#dog").click(function () {
            $.ajax({url: "https://aws.random.cat/meow", success: function (result) {
                    $("#thumbnail").attr('src',result.file);
                }});
        });
        $("#fox").click(function () {
            $.ajax({url: "https://aws.random.cat/meow", success: function (result) {
                    $("#thumbnail").attr('src',result.file);
                }});
        });

    </script>
```

Try in this way. You are creating several mistakes.

Comment: Why are you making AJAX requests to get files you can already access by path alone? This logic makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the description of the question that you simply want to change the `src` of an `img` when the buttons are clicked. You don't need AJAX for this. You can simply set the `src` property to the required image path.

Also note that the buttons need to be made in to `type="button"` elements, otherwise they will submit the parent `form` element and cause the page to be redirected. Try this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#thumbnail').prop('src', $(this).data('imgsrc'));
});
```

```css
#thumbnail {
  border: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 2px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="button" data-imgsrc="https://aws.random.cat/meow" name="cat" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Cat</button>
    <button type="button" data-imgsrc="https://aws.random.cat/meow" name="dog" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Dog</button>
    <button type="button" data-imgsrc="https://aws.random.cat/meow" name="fox" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Fox</button>

    <br>

    <img class="form-control" src="<?php echo $upload_path.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'];?>" id="thumbnail" />
  </form>
</div>
```